# How to connect an object automatically with user who is creating it and display those objects only which a specific user has created in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am making a real estate app in django and the problem i am getting is that a user can login in his account and begin creating his properties and then he can view those properties but what i am getting is the properties of every user on page while it should be only the propety that specific user created.

Here,s the models.py of property and i am using the django's user model

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Property(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')

STATUS_CHOICES = (
('R','Rent'),
('S','Sale'),
    )

status = models.CharField(max_length = 210,choices =     STATUS_CHOICES,default = 'None')

price = models.IntegerField(default = 'None')

area = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')

ROOM_CHOICES = (
('1','1'),
('2','2'),
('3','3'),
('4','4'),
('MORE','More'),
    )

rooms = models.CharField(max_length = 210,choices = ROOM_CHOICES,default = 'None')
BATHROOM_CHOICES = (
('1','1'),
('2','2'),
('3','3'),
('4','4'),
    )
bathroom = models.CharField(max_length = 210,choices = BATHROOM_CHOICES,default = 'None')
address = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')
state = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')
code = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')
images = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media',default = 'None')
info = models.TextField(max_length = 1000,default = 'None')
parking = models.BooleanField(default = False)
air = models.BooleanField(default = False)
swimming = models.BooleanField(default = False)
laundry = models.BooleanField(default = False)
dealer_name = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')
dealer_email = models.EmailField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')
dealer_number = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'Not mentioned')
user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name = 'user')



def get_absolute_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
    return reverse('profile_details:property', kwargs={'pk':self.pk,})
```

Also I want help with some course that can help me go through django completely and clearly so i can encouner these problems in the future.If you know any then please write down in comments.

Comment: If the user has logged in then the user object will be stored in `request.user` so to get the `property` of a user use `request.user.property_set.all()` in the `views`

Comment: Can you make that view?

Comment: see the answer by @Aurélien below it provides the two way of implementing the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got two options to get the properties of a user.

Using the `filter()` method:

```
# View to display the user properties
def properties_page(request):
    properties = Property.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'app/user_properties.html', {'properties': properties})
```

Using `_set.all()`

```
# View to display the user properties
def properties_page(request):
    properties = request.user.property_set.all()
    return render(request, 'app/user_properties.html', {'properties': properties})
```

Comment: Hi @UbaidParvaiz  if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Yeah i got another probelm